# Make a multiselect form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this select form to add in my database countries.

https://jsfiddle.net/Da4m3/394/

I want to change this form into this: 
[image]

this is html code:

```
<label class="margin-right10"><input type="radio" id="members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_0" name="members_create_campaign_form[countrySelectionType]" required="required" value="0" checked="checked" /> All</label>
            <label class="margin-right10"><input type="radio" id="members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_1" name="members_create_campaign_form[countrySelectionType]" required="required" value="1" /> Selected</label>
            <div id="clist_div" class="simplebox cgrid540-right" style="display:none;">
                <div style="padding:5px"></div>
                <div class="simplebox cgrid200-left">
                    <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Excluded Countries</b></p>
                    <select size="10" name="excludedcountries" style="width:200px; height:160px;" onDblClick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['excludedcountries'],this.form['members_create_campaign_form[countries][]'])" multiple >
                                                                                    <option value='97'>Afghanistan</option>
                                                                                                                <option value='191'>Aland Islands</option>
                                                                                                                <option value='105'>Albania</option>
                                                                                                                <option value='114'>Algeria</option>

                                                                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="simplebox cgrid40-left">
                    <input class="button-blue" type="button" name="right" value="&gt;&gt;" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['excludedcountries'],this.form['members_create_campaign_form[countries][]'])"><br/><br/>
                    <input class="button-blue" type="button" name="left" value="&lt;&lt;" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['members_create_campaign_form[countries][]'],this.form['excludedcountries'])">
                </div>
                <div class="simplebox cgrid200-left">
                    <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Selected Countries</b></p>
                    <select size="10" id="members_create_campaign_form_countries" name="members_create_campaign_form[countries][]" style="width:200px; height:160px;" onDblClick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['members_create_campaign_form[countries][]'],this.form['excludedcountries'])" multiple >
                                            </select>
```

and with this js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_1').is(':checked')) {
            $('#clist_div').show('slow');
        }
        $('#members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_0').click(function () {
            $('#clist_div').hide('slow');
        });
        $('#members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_1').click(function () {
            $('#clist_div').show('slow');
        });

        selectDiff('clist_div', 'members_create_campaign_form_countries');
    });
    function sortSelect(selElem) {
        var tmpAry = new Array();
        for (var i=0;i<selElem.options.length;i++) {
            tmpAry[i] = new Array();
            tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
            tmpAry[i][1] = selElem.options[i].value;
        }
        tmpAry.sort();
        while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
            selElem.options[0] = null;
        }
        for (var i=0;i<tmpAry.length;i++) {
            var op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
            selElem.options[i] = op;
        }
        return;
    }

    function SelectAllList(CONTROL){
        for(var i = 0;i < CONTROL.length;i++){
            CONTROL.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }

    function hasOptions(obj) {
        if (obj!=null && obj.options!=null) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function moveSelectedOptions(from,to) {

        if (!hasOptions(from)) { return; }

        for (var i=0; i<from.options.length; i++) {
            var o = from.options[i];
            if (o.selected) {
                if (!hasOptions(to)) { var index = 0; } else { var index=to.options.length; }
                to.options[index] = new Option( o.text, o.value, false, false);
            }
        }

        // Delete them from original
        for (var i=(from.options.length-1); i>=0; i--) {
            var o = from.options[i];

            if (o.selected) {
                from.options[i] = null;
            }
        }

        if ((arguments.length<3) || (arguments[2]==true)) {
            sortSelect(from);
            sortSelect(to);
        }

        from.selectedIndex = -1;
        to.selectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

how i can do that? i have tried but all time don't insert in to my database!

Is from this value allTarget that put me all, and this value countries[] for multiselect, i don't know where and how i can put this values.

**I have do some modifications and i have this code that when i select from left side is working, is adding to my database but when i push options to right side is not adding in database.**

```
    <div class="st-form-line">
        <span class="st-labeltext">Countries</span>
        <label class="margin-right10"><input type="radio" id="members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_0" name="www" required="required" value="0" checked="checked" /> All</label>
        <label class="margin-right10"><input type="radio" id="members_create_campaign_form_countrySelectionType_1" name="www" required="required" value="1"/> Selected</label>
        <div id="clist_div" class="simplebox cgrid540-right" style="display:none;">
            <div style="padding:5px"></div>
            <div class="simplebox cgrid200-left">
                <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Excluded Countries</b></p>
                <select size="10" name="countries[]" style="width:200px; height:160px;" onDblClick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['countries[]'],this.form['countries[]'])" multiple >
                                                                               <?php foreach($arrayCountries as $country) {?>
                                                <option value="<?= $country ?>" ><?= $country ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>

                                                                    </select>
            </div>
            <div class="simplebox cgrid40-left">
                <input class="button-blue" type="button" name="right" value="&gt;&gt;" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['countries[]'],this.form['countries[]'])"><br/><br/>
                <input class="button-blue" type="button" name="left" value="&lt;&lt;" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['[countries[]'],this.form['countries[]'])">
            </div>
            <div class="simplebox cgrid200-left">
                <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Selected Countries</b></p>
                <select size="10" id="members_create_campaign_form_countries" name="countries[]" style="width:200px; height:160px;" onDblClick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form ['countries[]'],this.form['countries[]'])" multiple >
                                        </select>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Any one? any idea?

Comment: your form seems to work as desired as-is; all countries drop down and the user is able to select multiple from the list; if this is just an aesthetic problem, you could use  jquery-ui and do a drag-and-drop list or something, but functionally it seems to work. As for the db issue, you'll need to elaborate more or add a more appropriate tag if your issue is with your db insert statement

Comment: You wish to change your form layout from that shown in the fiddle to that shown in the image?

Comment: You're asking someone to change what you've got. That isn't what SO is for. It's here to help with specific problems you're facing whilst doing the work yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly coded, but is this what you're looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/Da4m3/398/

(didn't bother to write the css)

The magic happens in the js code

```
s = $('#selected');
n = $('#not-selected');
l = $('#left');
r = $('#right');

l.on('click', function() {
    move = s.find('option:checked');
  move.attr('selected', false);
    n.append(move);
});

r.on('click', function() {
    move = n.find('option:checked');
  move.attr('selected', false);
    s.append(move);
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is true, but you have for forgott this two radio buttons one for select all and other when is selected it show me this multiselect.